# I want to implement Perps into article of Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to implement perps into article of Drupal 7.

Basically, all authorized user will be able to edit any of article and when they change any work or sentence in article then it will store like perps.

Article viewer will be able to see all perps and can be able to select any of the perps to read.

Can anyone help me, how to implement it?

Comment: What are perps? Do you mean you want to keep a revision of every edit?

Comment: When any logged in user will change any word or sentence in article then it will called as perps. Off course, we need to keep revision of every edit of each word or sentence of article.

Answer (score 0):

To keep a log of every change of word or sentence edit your content type and under Publishing Options tick "Create new revision".

This will then create a new revision of any content upon every edit.

If you then install the [diff module](https://drupal.org/project/diff) it will show you a visual representation of every change highlighting the words and / or sentences that have changed.

Comment: Thanks for info. I have done the same. Perhaps, i want to show some icon before changed word or sentence and on click of icon i have to show the revision list. User will be able to select any revision and after section that sentence or word will be loaded accordingly.

Comment: I am not aware of any module that has that functionality so I think your only option is going to be to create a custom module to add the functionality you need.